# Can I repair light scratches on a laminate countertop?

Tags: repair, kitchen-counters, laminate

I was foolish and scratched my laminate countertop, which I would like to repair. Everything I have found online shows solutions for filling in chips (or deeper cuts), mainly in laminate that has a uniform colour. My counter top varies in colour, and the scratches appear to only be in the top coating, so I am hoping there is another solution.

[image: Scratches in countertop]

If I wipe a damp cloth over the scratches the all but disappear, but once it dries again the scratches reappear.

[image: Scratches after applying a damp cloth]

Is there something I can do to recreate how it looks once damp, but permanently?

Comment: yes, you can treat just the clear finish to bring it to about 80% better. That's not actually the hard part, which is not having the background surface around the scratches become too glossy or dull compared to the rest of the counter. You want to fill in the scratches, but remove the fill next to the scratches, without polishing the area next to the scratches. Since you likely don't want a water-based finish, you'll need some solvent that can handle your fill. A combo i would try is clear nail polish and remover (acetone) soaked into a magic eraser; trace the scratch, then rub shortly after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth trying a high-quality paste wax before going too crazy with more involved fixes. Applied correctly you shouldn't even notice the wax. If you mess up or dislike it, wax is soluble in acetone so it's easily removed. You can't really make anything worse, in other words.

Comment: I like Howard's Butcher Block Conditioner. It's food safe ;-)

Comment: Thank you both, I have ordered some Howard's Butcher Block Conditioner, hopefully it has a marked improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Try rubbing a little oil into a scratch and see if it helps. this would not be a permanent fix and would have to be done frequently. A more permanent fix would be to get a set of colored magic markers and dot in the appropriate color into the scratch. This takes a while but lasts a long time.